# tcolorbox - "raster equal height" not work with nested tcbitemize

Tags: tcolorbox

I construct a raster by `tcolorbox` in which nested `tcbitemize` exists. I want boxes in the same line have the same height, so the option `raster equal height=rows` is used which seems not work as shown on the attached figure composed by the following MWE -- Same height with the box #1 and #2 is wanted, but they don't. Why and how to solve this problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[title=\#\thetcbrasternum,
                   raster columns=4,
                   raster equal height=rows]
  \tcbitem 1
  \tcbitem[raster multicolumn=3]
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3]
      \tcbitem 1 \tcbitem 1 \tcbitem 1
      \tcbitem 2 \tcbitem 2 \tcbitem 2
      \tcbitem 3 \tcbitem 3 \tcbitem 3
    \end{tcbitemize}
  \tcbitem 4
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile the document twice. `raster equal height=rows` writes the height of each box in the `tcbraster` to the `.aux` file and uses it when the `.aux` file is reread. This is necessary, because for instance, in order to compose the first box correctly (i.e., for final output), one needs to know the natural height of each box in the first row, which is impossible without using information from a previous TeX run.

After two compilation runs, your unmodified source produces:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you @frougon. By your kindly answer, I find the problem. After delete the original .aux file, twice of compilation give the result I want.